# HTML5 rendering diacritics

Tags: html, diacritics

I was just wondering whether diacritics need to be transformed to entities or can be just copy-pasted into my source code, providing that I have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my `<head>` section of my document.

I remember that diacritics for a specific language render only if the browser's language is set to that specific language. Otherwise, strange characters will be displayed. Am I right? What can I do to make sure that certain diacritics will display correctly in any language regardless the browser's language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With UTF-8 setting in `<head>` it works without problems. ľščťžýáíäňôř

Comment: So I can use all of these characters `aáiíoóuúyýsștțaăaâiî` simply by copy-pasting them in my code? And it will work on any browser which uses any language?

Comment: Yes! http://pastehtml.com/view/1echi0j.html . Another thing is of course the font support - but all the web-safe fonts are supporting these characters.

Comment: You might have issues on Windows XP. I don’t think the built-in fonts there include glyphs for much outside of the windows-1252 text encoding.

Comment: I don't think this is true, since Windows XP has Romanian (if I'm not mistaken about the characters above) language distribution, so all the fonts need to contain these.